# A check answer method in mysqldb-python

Tags: mysql-python

I want to check user input into an entry box widget against mysqld values and put out a messge in a messagebox saying that his answer is correct or wrong. An example can be a database with names and phone numbers; if a user enters the correct phone number for a given name then the message box says "You are right". Otherwise "you are wrong". The name and phone number are in mysqld database. So the user sees only the name in one of the entry boxes and the other entry box will be empty for him to enter the phone number. Can you please help me.

```
# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Execute the SQL command
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM PHONES")

# Fetch all the rows in a list of lists
row0 = cursor.fetchone()[0]
row1 = cursor.fetchone()[1]
row2 = cursor.fetchone()[2]

#checking the values in a single row
if row1 == nameVar.get() and row2 == phoneVar.get():

    tkMessageBox.showinfo("MCPHS Alpha Brand & Generic","You are right.") 

elif row1 != nameVar.get() and row2 != phoneVar.get():

    tkMessageBox.showerror("Check answer","Wrong answer")
else:

    tkMessageBox.showerror("Check answer","Enter an answer")


# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

And then i will call the method like this

```
  b7 = Button(frame2,text="Check Answer",command=checkAnswer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `cursor.fetchone()` incorrectly. It returns a single row, i.e. a tuple of column values, but will return `None` if there are no more rows in the result set. You seem to be trying to get column values, but you're calling `fetchone()` multiple times, so you are getting different columns from each row.

Your SQL query `SELECT * FROM PHONES` is flawed: There is no WHERE clause, so this selects every row in the table, which is probably not what you want. By using the `*` symbol, there's no way for readers to know exactly what columns are being returned; and they may be returned in an unexpected order. I am going to guess that you want something like this:

```
name = nameVar.get()
cursor.execute("SELECT phone from PHONES WHERE name=%s", (name,))
row = cursor.fetchone()
if not row:
    # row matching name not found
    break
phone = row[0]
# compare to submitted values
```

Alternately, you can use the SQL `COUNT()` function:

```
name = nameVar.get()
phone = phoneVar.get()
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PHONES WHERE name=%s and phone=%s", (name, phone))
count = cursor.fetchone()[0] # this query should always return exactly one row
if count:
    # data matched
else: 
    # it didn't match
```